# Виндосовский перевод строки на линуксе

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows, print

Можно ли использовать `print()` на линуксе так, чтобы новая строка была `\r\n`, а не `\n`? Кроме явного указания этих символов. Типа вызвать какую-нибудь функцию из `os/sys`, которая бы поменяла *linux newline* на *windows newline* во всех моих `print()`?

Comment: Цель какая? в файл писать?

Comment: @strawdog обычный `print()` на консоль

Comment: Для чего вам `\r\n` при выводе на консоль? При выводе это отобразиться просто как два переноса строки. Вообще разница в символах окончания строки важна при выводе в файл, а не при выводе на консоль.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Именно то, о чём вы спрашиваете, можно сделать так:

```
old_print = print
print = lambda *x: old_print(*x, end='\r\n')
```

И теперь при использовании `print` строка будет завершаться символами `\r\n`

Но вообще такие трюки обычно относят к категории "грязный хак", и их не стоит использовать в коде, который будет читать/поддерживать ещё кто-то кроме вас.

Я бы порекоментовал просто создать новую функцию:

```
my_print = lambda *x: print(*x, end='\r\n')
```

и далее использовать для вывода только `my_print`, а оригинальный `print` пусть остаётся без изменений.

Comment: То есть стандартных вещей для подобной "кросскомпиляции" нет?

Comment: @стас, по крайней мере, я каких-то стандартных решений для этого не знаю

Comment: Категорически не стоит вот таких штук  с built-in функциями делать!

Comment: Victor, почему же?)

Comment: @eri, а вы представьте себе, что вам необходимо работать с чужим кодом в большом проекте, в котором использовали подобный подход несколько раз в разных файлах... Представили? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Можно, для этого используется предпроцессор. Можно определить константу, которая в зависиости от задданных определений, будет делать сборку для windows и для linux разную. Как правило для проверки на линукс/виндовс используются определения `__linux__`, `_WIN32`, `_WIN64` их выставляет компилятор. В настройках проэкта можно задать параметры сборки.

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
   #define carrier_return "\n"
#elif _WIN32
   #define carrier_return "\r\n"
#elif _WIN64
   #define carrier_return "\r\n"
#else
   #warning choose windows or linux
   #define carrier_return "\r\n"    
#endif

print("your text" carrier_return );
```

У `с` в определенях строки можно использовать конструкцию `"строка1" "строка2"` - при этом конкатенация произойдет на уровне компилятора. Вместо `"строка2"` можно поставить макрос `carrier_return`.